# Copying jar file from my local hadoop node to a remote hadoop node

Tags: hadoop, jar, copy

I am a new to Hadoop. I have installed Hadoop on Mac OSX and I am able to run my Map Reduce java program on dataset present on my local system. Now I want to run this java program on a larger dataset which is stored on a remote Hadoop cluster. How do I copy my jar file onto this cluster in order to run it. I tried the put and copyFromLocal commands but am having no luck.

Answer (score 1):

How do I copy my jar file onto this cluster in order to run it.>

For this you can use WINSCP and Copy your jar or Hadoop program file to the remote cluster.
Once you have it on your remote cluster you can use the following command to compile the program.

$ mkdir hadoop_classes

$ javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/* -d hadoop_classess [path to + YourHadoopProgram.java]

$ jar -cvf yourhadoopprogram.jar -C hadoop_classess/ .

$ hadoop jar yourhadoopprogram.jar org.myorg.YourHadoopProgram [input path] [output path]

Check the following link for more understanding

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your jar file in the edge node of the cluster.Edge node - is the node onto which you log into the cluster.

You need not put your jar file in the HDFS to run the program.

Just run :

```
  Hadoop jar <jar-name> <arguments> <input_file> <output_path>
```

In case you pass input and output details then they should be your HDFS paths

Hope this helps !!